# Install venv for Python3.9 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: python-venv, python-3.9

I have successfully used venv in Python3.6.

I would like to use 3.9 on my Ubuntu 18. The Python is installed:

```
$ python3.9 -V
Python 3.9.16
```

I try to establish a venv

```
python3.9 -m venv venv
Error: Command 
'['/home/tevs/Dropbox/Programming/Python/pycharm/venv- 
probs/y/venv/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '- 
-default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I try to install ensurepip

```
pip3 install ensurepip
Collecting ensurepip
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ensurepip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ensurepip
```

I try to install python3.9-venv in the same way that I did for python3.6

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic Release                           
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:10 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 InRelease                     
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sane-project/sane-release/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:12 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release [1,731 B]       
Get:14 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release.gpg [836 B]
Err:14 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release.gpg   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EC34ED227AFAE3F2
Fetched 2,567 B in 1s (2,007 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EC34ED227AFAE3F2
W: Failed to fetch https://www.scootersoftware.com/dists/bcompare4/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EC34ED227AFAE3F2
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
[sudo] password for tevs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.9-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.9-venv' has no installation candidate
```

In Googling the error message I find advice like rebuilding Python3.9 from sources but I'm hoping to find something else or to have someone affirm that this is indeed the cure. I also find terse one-word references to pyenv and pipenv but I am not able to put context around those.

Any thoughts?